# silverlight content not working in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, silverlight, visio

I have an iframe inside an ASPX page like so:

```
<iframe id="mapFrame" name="mapFrame" src="project/visioMap.htm" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="900px" runat="server" />
```

The project directory holds Web page content exported by Visio.  I want to embed this content into the .NET Website without altering any of the content exported by Visio (ie. *.htm, *.js, *.xaml).  This is why I am trying to embed using the iframe tag.

However, when the page is loading, it crashes with the error:

```
TypeError: parent.parent.FindShapeXML is not a function
var shapeNode = parent.parent.FindShapeXML (pageID, shapeID); // in a *.js file
```

This error is in a *.js file exported by Visio, but like I said, I don't want to edit any of the files exported by Visio.  If I just open visioMap.htm, everything works fine, so an iframe pointing to it should work fine by default.

Apparently, parent.parent has a different meaning when I open visioMap.htm (which has a  with 2 frame) directly in the browser, and when I open visioMap.htm indirectly in the browser via an iframe.

Comment: We are experiencing this same problem. Have you found a solution? We have visio as html files that work, but if we re-publish using unaltered vsd files, they start breaking with exactly this error...

Comment: Also, do you have a timeframe that you can be sure this started in? We have it narrowed down to 8/21/2013-10/1/2013 And suspect a security update. It's weird though, considering old versions still work until republished.

Comment: @JCleveland did you find a solution to this? I'm banging my head against a keyboard... very little coverage on this online... any help would be much much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Visio "Save as Web" settings dialog has an option "Host in Web page".

[image]

By default, its value is "None". You can select here a web page, into which you would like to embed published content. Then it will be placed into `<iframe>` on this page. Alternatively, select "Basic" to have basic web page generated with `<iframe>` in it holding published content. This page HTML is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <iframe src="[Your visio file name]_main_2.htm" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto">
        <!-- No iframesupport --> 
    </iframe>
</html>
```

You can use this page directly or point your `<iframe>` to "[Your visio file name]_main_2.htm" referenced on this page.

Comment: I asked this question a while ago.  In the end I ended up using a Javascript plugin called panzoom to create a working solution.  I wasn't the one to export the content from Visio so I'm marking this as the answer, but note I didn't actually test this.  Thanks for your response some 3 years later :)